# What are dependencies of a state in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to understand the method [didChangeDependencies](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin/didChangeDependencies.html) and according to the definition

> It is Called when a dependency of this State object changes.

what do they mean by this. My guess is when properties in the state you manage per screen change. Am I right. Please I would love to understand better.

Comment: Look at this link https://mobikul.com/lifecycle-of-a-flutter-app/

Answer (score 0):

Try to think of it the same as `initState` but just a little later.

`initstate` is called before the state loads its dependencies and for that reason no `context` is available and you get an error for that if u use `context` in `initstate`. However, `didChangeDependencies` is called just few moments after the state loads its dependencies and `context` is available at this moment so here you can use `context`.

Answer (score 0):

In  case `BuildContext.dependOnInheritedWigetOfExactType` called, or in case the widget is been moved inside of the element tree, `didChangeDependencies` will is always called.